# How to render button in pyramid form

Tags: python, html, forms, schema, pyramid

I am working with pyramid to create a webpage.

According to an example in the documentation (attached), I can pass the form schema to the html template and select each field in the form and render then separately. This makes it very easy for me to style the form fields.

However, the example does not show how to render button components.

In the example attached, if I have a submit button,

$ form = deform.Form(schema, buttons=('submit',))

How would I render just the button in html, without re-rendering the fields again ?

[image]

UPDATE:

This is how I ended up using a custom submit button.

```
<div class="form-group text-center" tal:define="submit form.buttons[0]">
   <button name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">${submit.title}</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Buttons available via `form.buttons` list.

This is how buttons rendered in default form template (`form.render()`)

```
<div class="form-group deform-form-buttons">
    <tal:loop tal:repeat="button form.buttons">
        <button
                tal:define="btn_disposition repeat.button.start and 'btn-primary' or 'btn-default';"
                tal:attributes="disabled button.disabled if button.disabled else None;
                                attributes|button.attributes|{};"
                id="${formid+button.name}"
                name="${button.name}"
                type="${button.type}"
                class="btn ${button.css_class or btn_disposition}"
                value="${button.value}"
                tal:condition="button.type != 'link'">
            <span tal:condition="button.icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-${button.icon}"></span>
            ${button.title}
        </button>
        <a
                tal:define="btn_disposition repeat.button.start and 'btn-primary' or 'btn-default';
                btn_href button.value|''"
                class="btn ${button.css_class or btn_disposition}"
                id="${field.formid + button.name}"
                href="${btn_href}"
                tal:condition="button.type == 'link'">
            <span tal:condition="button.icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-${button.icon}"></span>
            ${button.title}
        </a>
    </tal:loop>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You render the attributes in a HTML button element.

```
<button value="{{ form.buttons[0].value|safe }}" name="{{ form.buttons[0].name|safe }}" class="{{ form.buttons[0].css_class|safe }}" type="{{ form.buttons[0].type|safe }}">{{ form.buttons[0].title|safe }}</button>
```

That for example would render the first button in your form as declared in the form schema.